# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: delphi

In this case I have some code which is working without problem in an existing program, but throws an excecption when I use it in a new program.

It may not be the best code, but it is working in every day use ...

```
Function  DoSQlCommandWithResultSet(const command : String; 
                                    AdoConnection : TADOConnection; 
                                    resultSet : TStringList): Boolean;
  var i : Integer;
      AdoQuery : TADOQuery;
begin
  Result := True;
  resultSet.Clear();

  AdoQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    AdoQuery.Connection := AdoConnection;
    AdoQuery.SQL.Add(command);
    AdoQuery.Open();

    i := 0;
    while not AdoQuery.eof do
    begin
      resultSet.Add(ADOQuery.Fields[i].Value);
      AdoQuery.Next;
      Inc(i);
    end;

  finally
    AdoQuery.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Yes, it probably needs a try/catch and the boolean result isn't used, but it works ...

.... in the previous program, but in a new one it thows an exception when called ...

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   var my_stringlist : TStringList;
       i : integer;
begin
   AdoConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);

   if ConnectToDefaultDatabase(AdoConnection) = False then
      MessageDlg('Agh !', mtError, [mbOK], 0);

   my_stringlist := TStringList.Create();
   if DoSQlCommandWithResultSet('show databases', AdoConnection, my_stringlist) = False then
      MessageDlg('Urk !', mtError, [mbOK], 0);

   for i := 0 to Pred(my_stringlist.Count) do
      memo1.Lines.Add(my_stringlist.Strings[i]);
end;  // FormCreate()
```

Now, here's the interesting part ... it throws the exception on `Inc(i)` and, if I replace that while loop with a for loop ...

```
    for i := 0 to Pred(ADOQuery.Fields.count) do
      resultSet.Add(ADOQuery.Fields[i].Value);
```

it works just fine.

I suppose that I could just use the for loop & move on, but I would like to understand what is going wrong .... can someone explain to me? Thanks

Comment: hmm, no comments, no answers and one down vote. Makes me wonder why he downvoted. And makes me want to suggest that downvoting not be allowed without an explanation. It's only good manneers, and one could lean from such explanations

Comment: you already have 2 answers...

Comment: not at the time it was downvoted without comment, I hadn't. I love this site, but sometimes the hit & run downvoters ...

Comment: It's worthy of a down vote because you don't take the trouble to explain what the exception is and where it occurs. Thus you force us to guess. Please learn to take more time over describing a problem. Doing so will also help you solve them unaided.m. Doing so will also help you solve them unaided.ing a problem. Doing so will also help you solve them unaided.m. Doing so will also help you solve them unaided.

Comment: hey Mawg,  David Heffernan has a point about describing the problem.  I find that while I am composing a great question, I often find the answer myself.  Maybe as much as half of the questions I start on SO never actually get posted because by sharpening the question more and more while "googling", I often find the answer myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that

```
i := 0;
while not AdoQuery.eof do
begin
  resultSet.Add(ADOQuery.Fields[i].Value);
  AdoQuery.Next;
  Inc(i);
end;
```

and

```
for i := 0 to Pred(ADOQuery.Fields.count) do
  resultSet.Add(ADOQuery.Fields[i].Value);
```

are *not* semantically equivalent!  When you call `Next`, you're advancing the current record in the dataset.  A loop until you hit `EOF` will run through each record in the dataset once.  But the second loop never calls `Next` and doesn't check for EOF; it's grabbing all the fields from one record.

If I had to guess what's causing the exception in the first loop, I'd say that you've got more records (rows) than fields (columns) in your dataset, and so after enough iterations, `i` ends up at `ADOQuery.Fields.Count` and you get an index out of bounds error.

What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: +1 agreed, they are different. Ooops, colums/rows ... you are correct, of couse. That looks like the problem. I will recode it, but Can you point me at some code for MySql access in general? Obiosusly, I need it

Comment: @Mawg: I don't know too much about MySQL. Again, what are you trying to do?

Comment: You found the answer!! I looked through thte old code & that function was only ever called with a quey that would return a single column of a single row.  When the new project wanted to return muliptle rows (one per database), so you were right about i and ADOQuery.Fields.Count  Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

In the while loop you are looping as often as there are are records

```
while not AdoQuery.eof do
```

but then you access the Field

```
ADOQuery.Fields[i]
```

while `i` represents the current "record number"...

This would crash in any program only depending on the relationship between record count of the query versus field count of the query... as soon as record count is higher than field count it crashes...

The for loop is part of the fix for this...

BUT since you don't provide the information whether you need all fields for one record or all fields of all records as `resultset` it is hard to provide fixed code...